# How does unity resolve the parameters of a constructor?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I've come across some code that looks like this:

`var something = this.container.Resolve<ICatManager>();`

which in the web config has a mapping from `ICatManager` to `CatManager`.

However, CatManager has a constructor which takes 2 parameters, and no default constructor.

How does unity manage to create an instance of it?

Comment: Is there a constructor section in the config for that type? Otherwise it could just use `default` values?

Comment: Nothing else in the config. Trying to find some documentation on how unity tackles it, but my search returns pages of results for 'how do I specify parameters'

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650894.aspx#cnstrctinj_single - maybe this provides an answer? (Automatic constructor injection)

Comment: Maybe the types of the constructor parameters are registered/mapped with unity as well? In that case unity just resolves them recursively. If the parameter types themselves have _parameterless_ constructors, unity can create an instance for each of them even without a mapping.

Comment: @Abbondanza yes this is the case and it states this in the link I provided.

Comment: How about you show the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Unity, and almost all other service container / service resolvers / service locators, work by analyzing the constructor(s) available, finding the "best one", then injecting parameters.

So, where does these parameters come from? From the service container itself.

For instance, if you have this service:

```
interface IService { ... }
class ServiceImplementation : IService
{
    public ServiceImplementation(IOtherService os, IThirdService ts) { ... }
}
```

then when you resolve `IService` Unity will try to also resolve `IOtherService` and `IThirdService` recursively. If the actual classes that implement those services also require other services, it does this resolution recursively until everything is OK.

So basically you could think of the resolution call like this:

```
var os = container.Resolve<IOtherService>();
var ts = container.Resolve<IThirdService>();
return new ServiceImplementation(os, ts);
```